# How to write a CSS hack for IE 11 with @media (max width 480px)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have seen an example here were you can hack IE using say for example

```
 @media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
   .foo { color: green } /* IE10 */
   *::-ms-backdrop, .foo { color: red } /* IE11 */
 }
```

I want to use the above code but also add  `@media (max width)` so i can change the margin left when the screen is smaller?

Comment: Not tested, but `@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) and (max-width: 350px) { //rules go here }` should work

Comment: no that didnt seem to work